# How to trim after splitting a string to list in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Following code from https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Tokenize_a_string#Common_Lisp splits a string at commas and send a list.

```
(defun comma-split (string)
  (loop for start = 0 then (1+ finish)
        for finish = (position #\, string :start start)
        collecting (subseq string start finish)
        until (null finish)
  )
)
```

However, the substrings will have blank spaces around them if they are there in original string.

```
> (comma-split " a, b ,c , d ,   e")
(" a" " b " "c " " d " "   e")
```

How can I add string-trim function to remove these spaces here. I cannot see a string variable that is being returned in the function.

I tried to have a local variable but it does not work:

```
(defun comma-split2 (string)
(let* ( (onestr "")
     ) 
  (loop for start = 0 then (1+ finish)
        for finish = (position #\, string :start start)
        (onestr (subseq string start finish))
        (onestr (string-trim onestr))
        collecting onestr
        until (null finish)
  )
))
```

Error on loading file:

```
*** - LOOP: illegal syntax near (ONESTR (SUBSEQ STRING START FINISH)) in
       (LOOP FOR START = 0 THEN (1+ FINISH) FOR FINISH = (POSITION #\, STRING :START START) (ONESTR (SUBSEQ STRING START FINISH))
        (ONESTR (STRING-TRIM ONESTR)) COLLECTING ONESTR UNTIL (NULL FINISH))
The following restarts are available:
```

Even trimming the outlist in a second function is not working:

```
(defun comma-split2 (string)
(let ( (outlist (list))
    (setf outlist (comma-split string))
    (dolist (str outlist)
        (push (string-trim str) outlist)
    )
    (nreverse outlist)
)))

> (comma-split2 " a, b ,c , d ,   e")

*** - LET: illegal variable specification (SETF OUTLIST (COMMA-SPLIT STRING))
The following restarts are available:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `COLLECTING`-statement is what is creating the list. So you need to put the call to `STRING-TRIM` around what is being collected.

```
(defun comma-split (string)
  (loop for start = 0 then (1+ finish)
        for finish = (position #\, string :start start)
        collecting (string-trim " " (subseq string start finish))
        until (null finish)))
```

You shouldn't put the closing parentheses on their own line.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not valid LOOP syntax. 
Either you use the simple syntax, which is like a PROGN but loops, or you use LOOP keywords, in which case you need to prefix statements with DO:

```
(loop 
  for i in list
  do
    (print i)
    (sleep 1))
```

You probably only need to do:

```
(loop for start = 0 then (1+ finish)
      for finish = (position #\, string :start start)
      collect (string-trim " " 
                           (subseq string 
                                   start 
                                   finish))
      until (null finish))
```

Alternatively, with regular expressions (see http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/):

```
(ppcre:split " *, *" string)
```

Comment: How can I use dolist here? I thought dolist is made for lists and should be the easiest to use here.

Comment: `NIL` is actually a valid end position for `SUBSEQ` (it's the default value, meaning rest of the string).

Comment: You are not iterating over a list, so dolist does not seem appropriate. Dolist simply binds a symbol to each element of the list, you need to add your own code to process and maybe collect the result, which is what LOOP does.

Comment: @jkiiski Thanks, I was confusing it with another one.

Answer (score 1):

Without proper indenting Lisp code you won't get very far.

Don't:

```
(defun foo (a)
(let ((b )
 b
))
 )
```

Write

```
(defun foo (a)
   (let (b)
     b))
```

Additionally: trying to write Lisp code without understanding Lisp syntax is also not a good idea.

**Trying to use a complex language by googling random code, trying to randomly modify the code and then posting the error messages to Stackoverflow isn't a very promising approach.**

Read one or more of the basic Lisp books:

- [COMMON LISP: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/book.pdf)
- [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/)

Use a Lisp reference: [Common Lisp Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/)

> LOOP: illegal syntax near

Read about LOOP, first.

> LET: illegal variable specification

Caused by lack of indentation and violation of Lisp syntax. Check the syntax of LET.

> How can I add string-trim function to remove these spaces here

How do you add functions at all?

Given this expression:

```
(sin 3.0)
```

How do you add a function to compute the square root?

Solution:

```
(sqrt (sin 3.0))
```

You call the function on the result of the the first one.

Simple as that. Why would you need additional variables?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the method string-trim .
For example

```
(string-trim '(#\Space #\Tab #\Newline) " Test   Test") =>  "Test Test" .
```

For more information you can go [here](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_stg_tr.htm).

I hope this will help you! :)

Comment: I know about this but I am trying to incorporate this in the function itself. Pl see my edit above.